# modularscale with breakpoints generate the same values for each breakpoint

Tags: css, sass, modular-scale

I'm using https://github.com/modularscale/modularscale-sass.

I have this setup :

```
$font-size-base: 16px;
$modularscale: (
  base: $font-size-base,
  ratio: 1.067,
  768px: (
    ratio: 1.125,
  ),
```

);

Then I use :

```
h1 {
  @include ms-respond(font-size, 12);
}
```

but the output CSS gives the same font-size value for the two breakpoints :

```
h1 {
  font-size:66px;
}
@media (min-width:768px){
  h1 {
    font-size:66px;
  }
}
```

Only the 1.125 ratio is used...

What am I doing wrong ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this to accommodate a gradual change over two or more breakpoints. However this requires two or more breakpoints like so:

`$font-size-base: 16px;
$modularscale: (
  base: $font-size-base,
  ratio: 1.067,
  450px: (
    ratio: 1.067,
  ),
  768px: (
    ratio: 1.125,
  ),
);`

Regarding “what am I doing wrong ?”

It totally makes sense that you should expect the behavior to work with one break point. I will open an issue to make this work as you expect it to.

Comment: Thanks. I also found this hacky solution. I already opened a ticket on the GitHub of modularscale. Thank you !